# Do all $T$-sets contain $0?$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definition, banach-spaces

Currently I am reading the book '[Isometries in Banach Spaces: Vector-valued Function Spaces and Operator Spaces, Volume Two](https://www.crcpress.com/Isometries-in-Banach-Spaces-Vector-valued-Function-Spaces-and-Operator/Fleming-Jamison/p/book/9781584883869)', Chapter $7,$ page $8.$

**Definitions**: A $T$-set is a subset $S$ of a Banach space $X$ with the property that for any finite collection $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in S,$
$$\left\Vert \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right\Vert = \sum_{j=1}^n \|x_j\|,$$
and such that $S$ is maximal with respect to this property.

**Definitions**: Two $T$-sets $S$ and $R$ in a Banach space $X$ are said to be *discrepant* if either $R\cap S = \{0\},$ or there exists a $T$-set $L$ such that $R\cap L = S \cap L = \{0\}.$

> **Question**: After reading the second definition, I guess that all $T$-sets contain $0.$
>   However, I fail to prove this.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jonas mentioned in his comment, the way to go about proving this is to use maximality.
Suppose $S$ is a subset of a Banach space $X$ with the property that
$$
\tag{1}
x_1,\ldots,x_n\in S
\implies
\left\|\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\right\| = \sum_{j=1}^n\|x_j\|.
$$
Then $S\cup\{0\}$ also has property $(1)$. Indeed, if $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in S$, then
$$
\left\|
\sum_{j=1}^nx_j+0
\right\|
=
\left\|
\sum_{j=1}^nx_j
\right\|
=
\sum_{j=1}^n\|x_j\|
=
\sum_{j=1}^n\|x_j\|
+0
=
\sum_{j=1}^n\|x_j\|
+\|0\|.
$$
Therefore, due to maximality, every $T$-set must contain $0$. (For otherwise, if $S$ is a $T$-set that doesn't contain $0$, then $S\cup\{0\}$ contradicts the maximality of $S$.)

Comment: Clear explanation. Thanks.